# How can I use this trim function for my textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, string, textbox, trim

How can I apply this trim function:  `var trimmed = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') ;` to this code below so that if a textbox contains whitespaces, it will display message "Incorrect"? Also If I use this function am I able to use "/" in the textbox because the textbox may contain data with "/".

```
  if (moduletext.value == ""){
      errmsg.innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    }else{
            errmsg.innerHTML = "Correct"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you're trying to do is check the trimmed value's length.

```
var trimmed = moduletext.value.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
if(!trimmed.length) {
  errmsg.innerHTML = 'Incorrect';
} else {
  errmsg.innerHTML = 'Correct';
}
```

If you know what browser you're using (generally anything not <IE9), you may be able to use the native browser implementation of trim, i.e. `'my string'.trim();`

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Scurker Answer is exactly what I am looking for so I will call this answer as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `replace()`, use a simpler expression with `match()`. The regular expression `/\s/` will match any whitespace in the textbox, and cause the `Incoorect` message.

```
if (moduletext.match(/\s/)){
  errmsg.innerHTML = "Incorrect";
}else{
  errmsg.innerHTML = "Correct"; 
}
```

You can include `/` in the textbox. Those `/` inside the regular expression are delimiters, not actual components of the expression.

Comment: It is not displaying a message underneath if it equals "" or contains whitespaces, I have put my attempt under your answer, have I done something wrong

Comment: If you can't see my edit then this is what I tried:               if (moduletext.value == ""){
          errmsg.innerHTML = "Incorrect";
            }else if (moduletext.match(/\s/)){
          errmsg.innerHTML = "Incorrect";       
        }else{
                errmsg.innerHTML = "Correct"; 
            }

Comment: @Michael Think about what that regular expression statement is saying.

`' '.match(/\s/); // true`
`'asdf'.match(/\s/); // false`
`'as df'.match(/\s/); // true`

Your expression matches _anything_ that contains spaces, which is contrary to what Malcom is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @scurker Yes,that is exactly what I intended with this regex, as that is what I understood _"if a textbox contains whitespaces, it will display message "Incorrect""_ to have meant. If that was not the OP's intent, it was not clear to me in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want a left and right trimmed string, and a way of updating a status field for your user.  These may be of interest to you:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
            //option 1: just determine if the string is valid
            string_valid = function (str) {

                validity_indicator = {
                    true:"Valid",
                    false:"InValid",
                };

                return validity_indicator[str.match( /\s*([^\s](:?.*[^\s])?)\s*/ ) != null];
            };

            // option 2: the trim and validation sort of wrapped up in one.
            parse_for_validity = function (str) {
                if ( ( result = /\s*([^\s](:?.*[^\s])?)\s*/.exec( str ) ) == null ) { 
                    return 'Incorrect';
                }
                return result[ 1 ];
            };

            // then either
            // errmsg.innerHTML = string_valid( your_string_here )

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- and then test them out -->
        <script> 
            alert( string_valid("    ") );       // => 'Incorrect'
            alert( string_valid(" abc ") );      // => 'Correct'
            alert( parse_for_validity("    ") ); // => 'Incorrect'
            alert( '...' + parse_for_validity(" abc ") + '...' ); // => '...abc...'
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With respect to the `/`, I believe you only have to concern yourself with it when you are using it within your regular expression.  Having `/` in the string you are testing against is fine.  If you want to test for a `/` in your regular expression, you should be able to escape it like this `\/`, as in the following expression: `/\//`

I hope this helps.  I love regex! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim(stringToTrim) {
return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");}
function ltrim(stringToTrim) {
return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+/,"");}
function rtrim(stringToTrim) {
return stringToTrim.replace(/\s+$/,"");}

calling : trim(document.getElementById('username').value);


used for removing all kinds of spacing...
```